# Разделение IdentityDbContext и DbContext - нужно ли?

Tags: c#, mvc, .net-core, asp.net-identity-2

Вопрос заключается в следующем. Я пишу небольшое приложение на .NET Core WEB API. И решил присоединить систему идентификации Identity. Но его присоединение требует создание контекста, который наследуется от IdentityDbContext. Но я уже использую свой контекст для остальной бд, который наследуется от DbContext.

Но вопрос состоит в следующем - как правильно делать ? Нужно добавлять Identity таблицы в существующую БД (т.е. мы от него будет наследоваться и пихать все в один контекст) или все таки стоит разделить на 2 контекста? И как тогда в случае двух контекстов создавать взаимодействие Identity и остальных таблиц ( в моей задаче я захотел расширить класс User и проставить свои роли).

Буду благодарен за ссылки на толковые ресурсы.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("YourContextName")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<UserModel> Users { get; set;  } // т.е. тут свои модели, не связанные с идентити
}
```

*Update*

По сути я хочу чтобы у меня был свой класс для Ролей, наследуемый от IdentityRole модели ролей ( нужны дополнительные поля помимо тех, что предлагает Identity) и свой класс User, который наследуется от IdentityUser.

Comment: Поясните, что значит проставить свои роли? `AspNet.Identity` уже содержит таблицу для ролей пользователей. А расширить класс `User` можно любыми свойствами. Так же, важно заметить, что у стандартной сущности `AspNet.Users` тип ключа — `uniqueidentifier`, что преобразуется в `string` (на деле это `Guid`). Уточните, пожалуйста, свой вопрос.

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk Хм, ну по сути я хочу чтобы у меня был свой класс для Ролей,
 наследуемый от IdentityRole модели ролей ( нужны дополнительные поля помимо тех, что предлагает Identity) и свой класс User, который наследуется от IdentityUser. Жаль, что переделываются под string (хотелось бы оперировать Guid, но ничего не поделаешь)

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk важно только одно - чтобы не поломать авторизацию такими манипуляциями

Comment: это все возможно. И Guid в качестве ключа, и дополнительные поля для ролей. Я так полагаю вам необходимы поля для добавления разрешения ролям?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разделение на два контекста не даст большого прироста производительности. Я бы использовал единственный класс `AppDbContext`, наследующий от `IdentityDbContext`.  В IdentityDbContext очень мало накладных расходов, это в основном обычный `DbContext с несколькими` `DbSet<>`. Если необходимо ограничить функциональность, разделяя на два контекста, то можно воспользоваться интерфейсами.

---

Что касается типа ключа для классов, то в этом случае используется несколько иная перегрузка `IdentityDbContext`. Приведу небольшой пример.

Для начала создам кастомные классы сущностей, чтобы не использовать длинные конструкции, вроде `: IdentityUser<Guid, IdentityUserLogin<Guid> ...`. Это необходимо, потому что мы используем другой тип ключа (`Guid`).

- UserClaim

  `public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid> { }`
- UserLogin

  `public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<Guid> { }`
- UserRole

  `public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid> { }`
- Role.

В качестве примера, расширим класс.

```
public class Role : IdentityRole<Guid, UserRole> 
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
}
```

- User

  `public class User : IdentityUser<Guid, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim> {}`

---

Сам контекст.

```
public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, Guid, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
```

В контексте переопределяем метод `OnModelCreating` и настраиваем наши поля.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
               .Property(x => x.Field1)
               .IsRequired();

   modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>()
               .Property(x => x.Id)
               .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

   modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
               .Property(x => x.Id)
               .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Буду от этого отталкиваться

Comment: @alexoander будут вопросы — задавайте :)